# codeigniter sending data to a model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter, model

I have an array of data based on an xml from facebook. How do i send that array to a model so that it can be inserted in the database ?

The array is formed in the view since the pages get redirected in the process of authentication with FB.So i need to get it from the view to a model.

I used the code given as an example here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ 
I'm using Server-side Flow

Comment: You need to be as clear as possible when asking questions.

Comment: I assume you're using the Client-Side flow?

Comment: If you're using the Client-Side flow, you need to use AJAX to send the array to a CodeIgniter controller.

Comment: No i'm using Server-side Flow

Comment: @andrei: How about sharing some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the server-side flow, your view isn't involved.  My understanding of the link you posted is that all of the auth actions take place on the server, in your controller or model...Am I missing something?

If this is the case, you'd just pass your data to the model the standard way, with function arguments.

The redirect_uri that you pass to facebook's credentialing system happens parallel with your server side process, not serial.

If I'm not understanding your question, you should provide more info in.your.question. so that we can better help.